# How to work with checkbox list in lotusscript?

Tags: checkbox, lotusscript

I'm developing a lotus notes application. I wonder how to check/uncheck and  enable/disable individual checkbox options from the checkbox list. This is how I did a work around to check it somehow:

```
Dim CheckListInitiator As String
CheckListInitiator = doc.CheckListInitiator(0)      ''get the checked items text in a variable.

''append the content of the required checkbox to the list. This will check it.

If CheckListInitiator = "" Then     ''if nothing checked, means the list is empty.
    CheckListInitiator = "Allotment Approval attached"          
Else    ''the list has one or more options checked, so append the content.
    CheckListInitiator = CheckListInitiator + "; Allotment Approval attached"           
End If
```

I'm not sure if this is the right way of doing this. Also I'm still unable to enable and disable individual items from the list.

Can anybody help on how to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would use an array variant to keep it simple.  What you need to create is a multivalue field, rather than a string with semicolons in it.

```
Dim checkListValues as Variant
  'turn this into a variant array
checkListValues = split("")
  'add the values currently selected and remove the blank
checkListValues = FullTrim(arrayappend(checkListValues, doc.CheckListInitiator))
  'add the value you want to add
checkListValues = ArrayAppend(checkListValues, "Allotment Approval attached")
  'return this list to the document
doc.CheckListInitiator = checkListValues
```

There are other ways to do this, with proper arrays and so on, but for me, this is the simplest way in LotusScript.

It's also VERY simple in @Formula language.

```
@Setfield("CheckListInitiator"; CheckListInitiator : "Allotment Approval attached")
```

Comment: @D.Bugger Absolutely correct.  A silly mistake, possibly caused by writing too much formula language lately. Edited and corrected

Answer (score 0):

You can get the selected values through doc.getitemvalue("[CheckBoxName]") this returns an array.
To set the checkbox, just do a doc.replaceItemvalue("[CheckBoxName]","[CheckBoxValue]") or doc.replaceItemValue("[CheckBoxName]",[checkBoxValues]) to set multiple values at the same time.

What values are available in a checkbox is defined in the notes form in the checkbox properties.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did it and it seems to work :

**To check the respective checkbox:**

```
Dim checkListValues As Variant
'Turn this into a variant array
checkListValues = Split("") 

checkListValues = Fulltrim(Arrayappend(checkListValues, doc.GetItemValue("CheckListInitiator")))
checkListValues = Arrayappend(checkListValues, "Allotment Approval attached")

Call doc.ReplaceItemValue ("CheckListInitiator", checkListValues)
Call doc.Save(True, False)
```

**To unchecked the respective checkbox:**

```
Dim checkListValues As Variant
''Turn this into a variant array
checkListValues = Split("") 

''Build array from the checkbox list, then remove the respective array element to update the list.
checkListValues = Fulltrim(Arrayappend(checkListValues, doc.GetItemValue("CheckListInitiator")))    
checkListValues = Fulltrim(Replace(checkListValues, "Allotment Approval attached","")) 
Call doc.ReplaceItemValue ("CheckListInitiator", checkListValues)
Call doc.Save(True, False)
```

Now the last point: I need to enable/disable the respective checkbox. Don't have a clue how to accomplish this. Is it possible?

Comment: any help on how to disable individual checkbox?

Comment: you can hide or display individual checkboxes, by changing the keywords, but you can't enable/disable individual checkboxes in Notes, as far as I know.